# Executing JSON blocks of PHP pseudo-code from JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

In the plugin I'm working on I want to provide the functionality to execute JSON blocks of PHP pseudo-code. I realized I would need to design a manner in which the JSON is specially formed that would allow my backend PHP to parse it and execute the pseudo code within.

Here is a JSON block in question before it is sent to the server as it exists in JavaScript:

```
var codeBlock = {
    opts: 
    [
        {
            http: {
                method: "GET",
                header: "Accept-language: en\r\n" +
                        "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
            }
        }
    ],
    context: 
    {
        stream_context_create: ['opts']
    },
    contents: 
    {
        file_get_contents: ['http://www.YourDomain.com/', false, 'context']
    },
    html: 
    {
        htmlentities: ['contents']
    }
}
```

In the above code block I'm telling PHP that I want to call `file_get_contents`. In order to do that I need to define an options array named `$opts` that is passed to `stream_context_create`. The returned results from `stream_context_create` are then to be stored in a variable named `$contents`. We then store the returned results from `file_get_contents` into a variable named `$contents`. Finally we convert the returned data from `file_get_contents` into the variable `$html`.

To start of course we would need to build a simple handler that sends our JSON to the server.

Most importantly we need to create a backend function to parse our results and send back our data.

The question is, how might we go about doing this in an open ended context (where any possible sequence of PHP functions calls and code might be passed)?

Comment: So would this allow someone to, say, call readdir or file_get_contents, so they can look for sensitive data on your server? Or could they DDOS your server by calling functions that hog resources?

Comment: Yes that would all be theoretically possible. Though in my implementation I have provided and am working to provide security measures that block function calls to dangerous functions. The user simplify customizes a black list. the other mode of operation is a white list that only allows the function calls provided in that list.

Comment: From what I've read, you're doing this because you're sometimes missing specific PHP functions in JavaScript? In that case, something like Haxe (http://haxe.org) might be interesting. It's a single language that can be compiled to multiple platforms, including PHP and JavaScript. I don't know how well it works in practice for a PHP/JavaScript scenario, but at least it doesn't mess up your client-server architecture. That, or a js library that provides the functionality you need.

Comment: As for the JSON format, in JavaScript, the properties of an object are unordered, so if the order of execution is important, `codeBlock` should be an array. And you're passing `opts` to a function, but what if you want to pass a string instead? Actually your JSON looks a little like a S-expression. :)

Answer (score 1):

The primary functionality that handles this dynamic parsing and execution of JSON "encoded" PHP is below. Essentially we parse the JSON sequentially identifying variable designations. When we come across a PHP object we then know within exists a PHP function call. We iterate through the arrays of a function's parameters looking for string "pointers" that we then replace with those pointers values. The pointers are just references to previously defined variables in our JSON that need to be sent as parameters to our function calls. Once our new parameters array is created we call the requested function with those parameters and then return the results back into that function objects variable definition where it may or may not be used as an argument for another function call down the line.

```
/**
 * Iterates over an array containing PHP and handles calls to enabled functions and executes them.
 * @param {phpObj} array A JSON decoded array of representational PHP.
 * @return {*} Will return the results of the last function call passed in through phpObj.
 */
function parse_php_object( $arr, $config ) {

    // We define a pointer array that contains reference names to parameter placeholders
    // that will be replaced by real data.
    $pointers = array();

    foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {

        // Create variable definition with our first level array keys
        ${$k} = $v;

        // Populate our pointers index
        $pointers[$k] = $k;

        // When a value is an object we attempt to call functions defined within
        if ( is_object( ${$k} ) ) {

            // Convert our function object to an array
            $funcArr = (Array)${$k};

            // Use the first key of the function array as our function name to call
            $func_name = array_keys($funcArr);
            $func_name = $func_name[0];

            // Get the array of arguments to parse to our arguments array
            $func_args = $funcArr[$func_name];

            // Create an array to store the arguments to pass to our function call
            $args_arr = array();

            // Now we iterate over our function arguments looking for reference strings
            foreach ( $func_args as $arg ) {

                // We compare against the keys in our pointers index which was created above
                if ( array_key_exists( $arg, $pointers ) ) {

                    // This is now a reference to ${$k}, the originally defined definition, the returned
                    // result of the last sucessful function call
                    $p = ${$arg};

                    // We push our arguments onto the args_array which will be passed to our function call
                    array_push( $args_arr, $p );

                } else {

                    // We push our arguments onto the args_array which will be passed to our function call
                    array_push( $args_arr, $arg );
                }
            }


            // Based on the security mode selected, use either our blacklist or whitelist.
            switch ( $config['SEC_MODE'] ) {
                case 'blacklist' :
                    if ( function_exists( $func_name ) 
                         && !in_array( $func_name, $config['LISTS']['blacklist'] ) ) {
                        $function_allowed = true;
                    } else {
                        $function_allowed = false;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'whitelist' :
                    if ( function_exists( $func_name ) 
                         && in_array( $func_name, $config['LISTS']['whitelist'] ) ) {
                        $function_allowed = true;
                    } else {
                        $function_allowed = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            // Call the requested function if permitted
            if ( $function_allowed === true ) {

                // Reassign our variable the returned value of a function call so that further function calls can
                // search for the existence of pointers and then use the updated variable definitions. This logic
                // takes advantage of the procedural nature of PHP and the order of the sub-blocks in the php object. 
                ${$k} = call_user_func_array( $func_name, $args_arr );
            } else {
                return ("Function you requested $func_name has been disabled by backend configuration.");
            }
        }

        // When we're not an object we're something else like an array, string, int, etc. If we're an array we need
        // to recursively iterate over ourselves to convert any objects into arrays.
        else {  
            if ( is_array( ${$k} ) ) {
                array_walk_recursive( ${$k}, 'object_to_array' );
            }
        }

    }

    // Return the returned result from our final function call
    return ${$k};
}

/**
 * Converts PHP objects to arrays by typecasting.
 * @param {object} Object A self referencing PHP object.
 */
function object_to_array( &$object ) {
    if ( is_object( $object ) ) {
        (Array)$object;
    }
}
```

I believe that this methodology uses a reflective pattern since command decisions are made based on the types of data passed. Furthermore this could be used with a great number of AJAX based projects without needing to specifically define handling interfaces for functions.

There is of course more code that does some type checking, security tests, and JSON encoding before we send our result back to our client but the functions shown above does the bulk of the lifting.